# UITableViewCell TitleLabel - unrecognized selector error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm setting up a simple tableview for my application but it seems like the code ain't working in XCode 6, it works in XCode 5. I get the SIGABRT error after the Launch Screen loads:

> 2014-12-19 13:44:06.584 TableTest Table[763:165564] -[UITableViewCell TitleLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14555e30
>   2014-12-19 13:44:06.586 TableTest Table[763:165564] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell TitleLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14555e30'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x21a4f49f 0x2f205c8b 0x21a548b9 0x21a527d7 0x21984058 0x4b7c3 0x251d7787 0x251d784b 0x251ccfa1 0x24fe50df 0x24f0f24f 0x24937a0d 0x249333e5 0x2493326d 0x24932c51 0x24932a55 0x25173055 0x25173dfd 0x2517e209 0x25172217 0x281e00d1 0x21a15d7d 0x21a15041 0x21a13b7b 0x219613c1 0x219611d3 0x24f761bf 0x24f70fa1 0x4bbd1 0x2f785aaf)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

I'm following a tutorial by GeekyLemon: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ITUI7fukRO8 and here is the code used:

I've pasted the code here, but the code is also available at this link: http://www.geekylemon.com/xcode-tutorial-table-view-p1

Thanks!

TableViewController.h:

```
@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController {
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *Images;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *Title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *Description;
@end
```

TableViewController.m
    @implementation ViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
      [super viewDidLoad];
      // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
      // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
      // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
      // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

        _Title = @[@"Big Ben",
                        @"Colosseum",
                        @"Great Wall of China",
                        @"St Basil’s Cathedral",
                        @"Statue of Liberty",
                        @"Stonehenge",
                        @"Taj Mahal",
                        @"The Eiffel Tower",
                        @"Tower of Pisa",];

        _Description = @[@"London, England",
                                  @"Rome, Italy",
                                  @"China",
                                  @"Moscow, Russia",
                                  @"Liberty Island, New York",
                                  @"Wiltshire, England",
                                  @"Agra, India",
                                  @"Paris, France",
                                  @"Pisa, Italy",];

    _Images = @[@"BigBen.jpg",
                        @"Colosseum.jpg",
                        @"GreatWallOfChina.jpeg",
                        @"StBasils.jpg",
                        @"StatueOfLiberty.jpg",
                        @"Stonehenge.jpg",
                        @"TajMahal.jpg",
                        @"EiffelTower.jpg",
                        @"TowerOfPisa.jpg",];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{ 
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return _Title.count;
} 

@end
```

TableCell.h

```
@interface TableCell : UITableViewCell {
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *TitleLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *DescriptionLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *ThumbImage;
@end
```

TableViewController.m again

```
#import "TableCell.h"

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCell";
    TableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier           forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    int row = [indexPath row]; 

    cell.TitleLabel.text = _Title[row];
    cell.DescriptionLabel.text = _Description[row];
    cell.ThumbImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_Images[row]];;

return cell;
}
```

Comment: if there is no reusablecell? how could you use the cell?

Comment: @WorldOfWarcraft I'm new to XCode, so i'm not sure what you mean. In TableViewController.m there is a line which states: TableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier           forIndexPath:indexPath];

Is this what you mean?

Comment: You are getting a `UITableViewCell` instance instead of a `TableCell` instance. Make sure you register the proper cell class with your table view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong: you are using the same name for a class `TableCell` with your name for `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`

To make it work...:

1) in your storyboard click on your cell and change the identifier.. let say `TableCell_identifier`

2) in you code change accordingly `static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCell_identifier";`

Answer (score 0):

It seems your code look alright. What you would be missing is that:

```
TableViewController.h:
1. @interface RootViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> 
2. At below line:
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCell";
    It should be either static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    or in your custom cell in storyboard/XIB, set TableViewCell identifier to "TableCell" as given in below image.
```

[image]

Comment: I changed what you wrote in TableViewController.h and renamed the (at)interface and (at)implementation in TableViewController.m from UITableViewController to RootViewController (is that right?). At least now it doesn't crash, but it ain't showing any data in the table. Here is the project, if you want to take a look: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l7hu6x2sdrs9iq3/InstaTags%20Table%202.zip?dl=0

Comment: I had downloaded your project. Have a doubt on it. Are you using TableViewController/TableCell or TableViewController3/TableViewCell3 files in your implementation? It is a minor error that would be causing this. Please also post the screenshot of the simulator/device after you run the project.

Comment: I think most probably the problem would be:                                                                1. In your storyboard, tableViewCell, it should inherit from class TableCell instead of UITableViewCell.                               2. You need to connect the UI labels in tableViewCell to corresponding items in TableCell, then only your Ui elements will be bound with TableCell class and will display on screen.

Comment: It works now! I followed TonyMkenu's answer and it worked. It was basically what you answered, but the "@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> " seemed to mess it up I guess. Anyway, thanks for the help, much appreciated :)